# Angular not printing JSON values in html

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using Angular 6 and Slim, i can receive the values correct the JSON, printed in the console. But when i try to print this values into my html there's no any value to print.

This is my component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { PostService } from '../../services/post.service';
import { Post } from '../../models/post';

@Component({
    selector: 'category-inf',
    templateUrl: './cat-inf.component.html',
    providers: [PostService]
})
export class catInfComponent{
    public tittle = 'Post tittle';
    public posts: Post[];

    constructor (
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _router: Router,
        private _postService: PostService
        ){
        this.tittle = 'Category virtualization';
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        console.log ('Category virtualization loaded');


    this._postService.getPost().subscribe(
        result =>{
                if(result.code != 200){
                    console.log(result);
                }else{
                    this.posts = result.data;
                    console.log(result);    
                }
            },
            error =>{
                console.log (<any>error);
            }

        );
    }
}
```

This is the component.html

```
 <h2>{{tittle}}</h2>
<hr/>
<div *ngIf="!posts">
    <p>Loading post...</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="posts">
    HOla

    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
            <strong>post</strong>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the post service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
//  npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Post } from '../models/post';
import { GLOBAL} from './global';

@Injectable()
export class PostService{
    public url: string;

    constructor (
        public _http: Http
        ){
        this.url = GLOBAL.url;
    }

    getPost(){
        return this._http.get(this.url+'posts').map (res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, i'm stuck here for some hours and i cannot see where is the problem.

Thanks for help.

Comment: are you seeing the values in console from console.log(result)? If so can you post the json here?

Comment: Yes, i can see the result in the console:{"status":"success","code":"200","message":[{"post_ID":"1","post_date":"2016","post_content":"valueone","post_category":"newcat","post_like_count":"1","post_comment_count":"1","post_image":"aa","article_title":"article tittle db","article_content":"Article content body"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

```ts
{
    "status": "success",
    "code": "200",
    "message": [{...}, ...]
}
```

... we can see that your response does not include a `data` property, so if you were to console log `result.data` in your callback, it would be `undefined`. What you are looking for is `result.message`, as your array is inside that:

```ts
this._postService.getPost().subscribe(result =>{
  if(result.code != 200){
    console.log(result);
  } else {
     // here!
     this.posts = result.message;
     console.log(this.posts);    
   }
  },
   error =>{
     console.log (<any>error);
   });
}
```

Also you should definitely move to [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http) instead of using the old `Http`. And then mentioned in another answer, you need to use interpolation in the view:

```html
<li *ngFor="let post of posts">
   <strong>{{post.post_ID}}</strong>
   <!-- ... -->
</li>
```

Comment: You did the rule. Changing result.data by result.message it works like a charm. I would investigate about the httpClient.

Thanks for the help to all.

Comment: Yes, look into the HttpClient, `Http` is deprecated. You can also find the [interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) very useful for example in the future :) N.B, only works with `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 0):

If your json is empty you can see it in the view with the pipe json. Like this {{var | json}}

Comment: In this part this.posts = result.data; console.log(result); I can see the result in the console with the good result.